# Faild on get ImageFileName form PsSetCreateProcessNotifyRoutineEx

Tags: c, callback, kernel, createprocess

I,m developing a simple driver to notify process creation to user mode !
I searched an found some good example but that's only show result in "dbgView" !

My problem is retrieve and send the : `ImageFileName` and `CommandLine` from `PPS_CREATE_NOTIFY_INFO CreateInfo`.

This is my code in side the `CreateProcessNotifyEx` callback :

```
VOID CreateProcessNotifyEx(
    __inout   PEPROCESS Process,
    __in      HANDLE ProcessId,
    __in_opt  PPS_CREATE_NOTIFY_INFO CreateInfo

    )
{ ...

            Pinfo->ParentId = CreateInfo->ParentProcessId;
            Pinfo->ProcessId = ProcessId;
            Pinfo->Create = CreateInfo->CreationStatus;
            Pinfo->ImageFileName= CreateInfo->ImageFileName;
                    Pinfo->CommandLine= CreateInfo->CommandLine;

..
            KeSetEvent(ProcessEvent, 0, FALSE);
            KeClearEvent(ProcessEvent);
....}
```

This code work perfectly and i got the [b]Pinfo[/b] struct in user mode, but the `Pinfo->ImageFileName` and   `Pinfo->CommandLine` does not contain any string ! (Pinfo->ProcessId and Pinfo->Create fills by true data)

Where is my wrong ?

{Ohhh Excuse my if my English is bad}

Comment: As per the documentation of that API, this information may not be available through that api.

Comment: @Rohan No I'm sure this info is available because when use `dbgprint(" %ws",CreateInfo->ImageFileName)`. Write the value of `CreateInfo->ImageFileName` in *DebugView*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Pinfo->ImageFileName= CreateInfo->ImageFileName;
Pinfo->CommandLine= CreateInfo->CommandLine;
```

These are `PUNICODE_STRING` type variables. And from the documentation page

> The PS_CREATE_NOTIFY_INFO structure and the structures that it points to are guaranteed to be valid only for the duration of the callback. If the driver requires access to any information from these structures after the callback, the CreateProcessNotifyEx routine should make a copy of this information.

It suggests that you should allocate new memory for  `Pinfo->ImageFileName` and `Pinfo->CommandLine` and then copy the unicode strings into it.

Otherwise, memory that you are trying to access may not be valid and may not contain same information after it exists the callback.

Also, do not forget to free the memory after its use is over.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm new in driver programming and I'm not familiar with kernel mode memory management to allocate buffer and ... 
Please if it's possible show me a simple example about this  .